# AutoPostBack for custom controls

Tags: asp.net

If there is anyway to implement the auto post back support to custom controls.Now like to create the button control with auto post back property then,which interfaces must inherited,and how to implement.

Thanks for Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special Javascript function handling Postback event `__doPostback()`, when you call this function the page will be posted back. In ASP.NET, it also has two hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
```

You can research by yourself when you look at HTML source code of an rendered ASPX file.